# Permutations of Combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have 6 letters ABCDEF and you must create all possible sets of at least 1 of these characters. The characters in the sets must be arranged in order and are unique. In addition, the C character is a variable which can be replaced by 1 of 3 values ie (C1, C2, C3). Is there a formula that can be derived to calculate the total number of sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem seems equivalent to counting (non-empty) subsets.

First consider all the subsets that don't contain $C$, I.e. all the subsets of $\{A,B,D,E,F\}$. There are $2^5-1$ such non-empty subsets.

Now consider all the subsets that contain $C$. We can find this by counting all the subsets (possibly empty) of $\{A,B,D,E,F\}$ and then adding $C$ to each of these subsets. Thus, there are $2^5$ subsets that contain $C$. For each of these $C$ may take on $3$ different values, so by the multiplication principle, there are $3 \cdot 2^5$ sets that have some version of $C$.

In total there are $(2^5-1)+(3\cdot 2^5)$ such sets.